# How to mock environment variable check from function initialization before test?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a decorator function that gets some data from environment variable. So in the beginning I check that this environment variable is set.

```
function dec(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  if (!process.env.NAMESPACE) {
    throw new Error('The environment variable NAMESPACE was not set.');
  }
  ...
}
```

Then I use this decorator for a function.

```
@dec
function foo() {
...
}
```

I try to test function `foo()` with `jest` unit tests. The test fails if I didn't set NAMESPACE variable on my laptop. If I try to set it up in `beforeAll` section it still fails. Somehow function `dec` is called earlier than `beforeAll`. How to set up NAMESPACE variable in test earlier than `dec` is called?

Comment: you shouldn't read environment variables within a decorator function. Pass it as configuration. That way it'll be much simpler to mock in tests as well. A better design overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jest, you can configure a setup file that is ran before tests & before jest hooks ("beforeAll / beforeEach").

In `jest.config.js` (or .ts) you have a `setupFiles` property.

You just have to add in jest.config.js :

```js
{
    ...
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
}
```

Inside `jest.setup.js`, just add all your env variables for testing purpose :

```js
process.env.NAMESPACE = 'Test-Namespace';
```

You can eventually use `setupFilesAfterEnv` property is needed. The order is :
setupFiles > setupFilesAfterEnv > beforeAll > beforeEach > afterEach > afterAll